# How to use the word “restriction”

Tags: word-usage

I am not sure about the usage of the word “restriction”. I would like to use it in a sentence like: “This video has some distribution and/or age restrictions”.

Can I use “has some” or is there a better way?

Comment: You could say it, but it's rather pointless. What do you mean, *some* restrictions? If I should care about the restrictions, clearly state what they actually are. And if I should not care about them, mentioning them without actually mentioning them is just a waste of space and time.

Comment: I totally agree with RegDwight. If I should care about the restrictions, you can say _This video is intended for people aged  ?+_ if there is an age. If I should not, why do you need such a sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible alternatives to “has some restrictions” include the following:

- is subject to some restrictions
- is under some restrictions
- carries some restrictions

The version with *has* is the most common, per Google-Books [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20some%20restrictions%2Cis%20subject%20to%20some%20restrictions&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), followed by the first of the bulleted ones. The others, somewhat to my surprise, apparently did not occur in their corpus.

You might also try building your sentence around the passive verb *is restricted.*